# Waiting for an async call to finish before submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

This one is a bit tricky.

So here's my jQuery code:

```
/**
 * Updating websites
 */
$('.website').on('blur', function () {
    var websiteId = this.id;
    console.log(websiteId);
    var website = this.value;
    console.log(website);
    fetch(`/api/edit/${websiteId}&${website}`).then(() => {

    });
})
```

Here's my HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <% for(let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i]; %>
    <fieldset id="site<%= i %>">
        <p style="color: <% if(errorMsgs[i] === 'Wrong website address'){ %> red;<% } else { %> green;<% } %>
                padding-bottom: 0;
                padding-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 0;"
           class="">
            <%= errorMsgs[i] %>
        </p>
        <div class="">
            <input class="website"
                   name="website<%= i %>"
                   id="<%= i %>"
                   value="<%= website %>"
                   type="text"/>
            <a href="/websites/edit/<%= i %>"
               class="btn btn-info hide">
                Edit
            </a>
            <a href="/websites/delete/<%= i %>"
               data-id="<%= i %>"
               class="btn btn-danger confirmation removeBtn">
                Remove
            </a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
    <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2"
            value="Generate a report"
            name="generateReport"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#exampleModal">
        Generate a report
    </button>
    <!-- Save button created using Javascript. In case JS is disabled -->
</form>
```

Here's my API

```
// GET: api/edit/_id - save updates
router.get('/edit/:_id&:url', (req, res, next) => {
    Account.findById(req.user._id, (err, acc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            acc.websites.set(req.params._id, req.params.url);
            acc.save((err, webs) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('all good');
                    // res.redirect('/reports');
                    res.json(webs);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How it works: The user inputs the value into the input fields, on blur, I make an AJAX call to the API, the value is saved in the db. And all this works.

There is one problem though. If the user hits the submit button, the fetch has no time to run. And it makes sense.

But I need the submission to wait until the value is updated. I was thinking about doing smth like, adding a `preventDefault` to the submit button, then after it's saved, removing the `preventDefault`.

But I have no idea how to do it, if it's a good idea or even if it makes any sense.

So to recap: I need the form submission to wait until the AJAX call is finalized.

This `<% smth %>` is just the `EJS` templating system. Shouldn't affect how it all works.

Comment: can't you set the disabled attribute on the button and remove it once you get the response in your .then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `fetch()` returns a promise.  Save those promises in a shared variable.  In your submit button code, use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises to resolve.  Something like:

```
const fetchPromises = [];
$('.website').on('blur', function () {
    var websiteId = this.id;
    console.log(websiteId);
    var website = this.value;
    console.log(website);
    var fetchPromise = fetch(`/api/edit/${websiteId}&${website}`).then(() => {

    });
    fetchPromises.push(fetchPromise);
});
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Promise.all(fetchPromises).then(() => this.submit());
});
```

You may want to add some error handling.  If any of your `fetch()` calls fail, that will prevent the form from being submitted.  Ideally a failed AJAX call would result in some messaging to the user that, once dismissed, removes the promise from the `fetchPromises` array, and until it is dismissed, the submit button should be disabled (actually, and visibly).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this just adds the promises to the array, and runs them on the submit event. Is that right?

Comment: Nothing changes with the `fetch()` calls.  The underlying AJAX requests are made at the same time as your current code.  We are storing the returned promises _just in case_ the submit button is clicked before the promises resolve.  If the AJAX requests finish before the form is submitted, `Promise.all()` will resolve immediately, and the form submission will go through without delay.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

How about making a fake submit button with a `preventDefault` and hiding your real submit button with `display:none`?  Then you can call a `click()` function on the hidden button once you've got your AJAX success.

Comment: Damn that's sneaky. I'll give it a shot

Comment: You don't need to hide a button.  A form has a `submit` method that you can call.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your button to a disabled state, add a listener to it, then throwing an event during your .then() function.

```
$('.website').on('blur', function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById('submitButtonId');

    // create the event
    var isFinishedEvent = new Event('fetched');

    elem.addEventListener('fetched', function() {
        // logic to enable your button
    }

    var websiteId = this.id;
    console.log(websiteId);
    var website = this.value;
    console.log(website);
    fetch(`/api/edit/${websiteId}&${website}`).then(() => {
       // Fire the event
       elem.dispatchEvent(isFinishedEvent);
  });
})
```

Comment: I think I'll combine your and p0rter's answers. Give me a second